# width animation in Jquery is not wokring

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, width

Jquery works fine with other stuff

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {   
        $("#no").mouseover(function() {
            console.log("hover")
            $("#no").animate({width: "25%"},600)
        })
   })
</script>
```

whenever I hover ,I see the message in console but no width change.
Edit: I did set width before and it does not work

Comment: Set a width first (eg 0) - jquery can't animate from/to "auto"

Comment: Please add the relevant html and css code, ideally as a snippet. As you can see in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0a9kx4sL/), your code works. (At least with jQuery 3.4.1)